# How should you unit test HATEOAS and controllers returning HATEOAS?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I have a spring boot application that uses HATEOAS's RepresentationModelAssembler. How should one unit test classes that implement RepresentationModelAssembler? I could not find any examples online.

Another issue I had was testing Controller classes using standAloneSetup to create a MockMvc. The JSON returned by my endpoints in an integration test (@SpringBootTest) and during active deployment has links under "_links" and embedded under "_embedded". During a controller test using standAloneSetup links were under "links" and embedded under "content". Why is this different and how do I fix it to be in line with what is expected of the live application?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1, what do you want to unit test a class that implements `RepresentationModelAssembler`? Test the method `toModel` or `toCollectionModel`?

Question 2, depending on any other maven dependencies and your configuration, during active deployment, the media type of a response of type `ResponseEntity<CollectionModel>` returned by a controller should be [application/hal+json](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/MediaTypes.html#HAL_JSON), which contains `_links` and `_embedded`.
Depending on how you write your test, the default request accept is plain `application/json`.
Try

```java
mockMvc.perform(
        get("/xxx")
                .accept(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON))
       .andExpect(status().isOk())
       .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON))
```

Just a suggestion, uploading an runnable example project to Github always help others understand and answer your question.